# Does accept() bind returned fd to a new port?

Tags: networking, port

accept() returns a new fd which does read/write to the client, does it also bind the new fd to another port other than the listened one? Or messages to the new fd also go through the original port the server is listening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> does it also bind the new fd to another port other than the listened one?

No. The local port of the accepted socket is the same as the local port of the listening socket.

> Or messages to the new fd also go through the original port the server is listening?

The question is ill-formed. 'Messages' don't 'go through' ports at all. Ports aren't much more than just numbers with a dozen states. Data is delivered over *connections.* The accepted socket represents a connection. Another accepted socket represents a different connection.

Comment: So multiple "connections" spawned by the same listening socket share the same port number as the listening socket, right?